# How to search for a second pattern only for the files where the first pattern was found - both pattern printed

Tags: linux, bash, grep

I have a bunch of files that are originally created from a template.
It means that I know that the mentioned tags exists in all these files!
(I hope that is okay for Ed as well!)

I have simplified the originally files when sharing this case here. Only four files with two parameters/tags each.

```
$ cat file1.tt file2.tt file3.tt file4.tt
#region owner
// kalle
#endregion
#region status
// open
#endregion
#
#region owner
// berra
#endregion
#region status
// Open
#endregion
#
#region owner
// sune
#endregion
#region status
// test
#endregion
#
#region owner
// sixten
#endregion
#region status
// analyze
#endregion`
```

a)
The first thing I want is to find all files that have tag "status" value other than "open" or "Open".
And I want the printout to show the file name and the actual status.

That is something I have already. (Presented further below)

b)
But I also want to see the tag "owner" for the files that was found in "a" above.
That result can be printed on the line after the "status" info in "a". Something like this would be great,

```
file3.tt-// test // sune
file4.tt-// analyze // sixten`
```

I have a command to print the "owner" tag value for all files. But not the solution I request according to above.

The printout format isn't that important as long as the information for each file are well separated:
The two tags could also be printed on separate lines after the file name. And then a empty line before next file name. And so on...

So far I can easily get what I want in "a" with this:

```
grep -rA1 --include='*.tt' '#region status' | grep -v '#region status' | grep 'tt' | grep -v --ignore-case open

file3.tt-// test
file4.tt-// analyze
```

And for "b" I have this command. But this will print "owner" for all files.

```
grep -rA1 --include='*.tt' '#region owner' . | grep -v '#region owner'

./file1.tt-// kalle
./file2.tt-// berra
./file3.tt-// sune
./file4.tt-// sixten
```

But what I want is a combination "a" and "b": just to print the "owner" for the files found in "a". So the file name together with the "status" and the "owner" should be printed only when the "status" tag is different from "open"/"Open".

One liners is what I look forward to see.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

`grep -v` prints the *lines* that don't match the pattern, it doesn't exclude the whole file.

Use a loop with `if` to test whether the file contains `open`. Then you can use `sed` to print the line after `#region owner`.

```
for file in *.tt; do
    status=$(sed -n '/#region status/{n;p;q}' "$file" | tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]')
    if [[ $status != *open ]]
    then
        owner=$(sed -n '/#region owner/{n;p;q}' "$file")
        printf '%s-%s-%s\n' "$file" "$owner" "$status"
    fi
done
```

Comment: Hi Barmar,

Not sure about your "grep -v" comment since I'm already using it in "a" as I shared in my original post.

Also, added " to the end of your script so I could run it.
But it doesn't show the "status", only the "owner".

Anyway, I'm looking forward to get a simpler one liner reply to this from someone.  :-)

Take care.

Comment: I thought you just wanted the owners, not the status in your output. I've updated the answer to get both. Now I don't need to use `grep` at all, since I just test the status value directly.